# Take picture on Macbook login (successful or failed)

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

I'm looking for a way to have a picture taken with the Macbook camera every time there's a login attempt (either successful or failed) and save it to a folder on my computer. From there I know how to automate the process of emailing that photo or upload it to an FTP.

I found there's an old program called [Spy Lock](https://itunes.apple.com/ar/app/spy-lock/id475179790?mt=12) claiming to do that, but it is indeed old, and a solution not involving third-party software would be preferable.

How can I have the Macbook save a webcam picture after each logon attempt?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Its one way to work out who stole your laptop ;p

Comment: bump!!v i would like this as well